# import error when I test scikit on ubuntu12.04

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn

I want to install scikit on ubuntu12.04 and I followed the instruction on [the official installing documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)and type the following command in the bash:
    sudo apt-get install python-sklearn

next I type the test instruction 
    nosetests sklearn --exe

But I got many import errors! I searched google but found little useful links. I'm new to python and I want to learn python and machine learning through scikit.So please help me, thank you.

Below are the error information when I run the nosetests command in bash.Due to the length limitation, I deleted some error.

```
  EEEEEE..............EE.....EE........EE.............EEE......EE..........
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named joblib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cluster/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .hierarchical import ward_tree, Ward, WardAgglomeration
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cluster/hierarchical.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from joblib import *
ImportError: No module named joblib

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named joblib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/covariance/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .graph_lasso_ import graph_lasso, GraphLasso, GraphLassoCV
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/covariance/graph_lasso_.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ..linear_model import lars_path
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .least_angle import Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LARS, LassoLARS, \
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from joblib import *
ImportError: No module named joblib

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named joblib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from joblib import *
ImportError: No module named joblib


======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named joblib)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from joblib import *
ImportError: No module named joblib

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Parallel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_extraction/tests/test_text.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Parallel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_selection/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .rfe import RFE
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Parallel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .least_angle import Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LARS, LassoLARS, \
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/metrics/cluster/tests/test_unsupervised.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .... import datasets
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/metrics/tests/test_metrics.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ... import datasets
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/utils/tests/test_sparsefuncs.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/utils/tests/test_svd.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_low_rank_matrix
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
ERROR: Tests that clone creates a correct deep copy.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_base.py", line 48, in test_clone
    from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFpr, f_classif
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_selection/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .rfe import RFE
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Tests that clone doesn't copy everything.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_base.py", line 64, in test_clone_2
    from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFpr, f_classif
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_selection/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .rfe import RFE
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/feature_selection/rfe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: sklearn.tests.test_base.test_is_classifier
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_base.py", line 109, in test_is_classifier
    from ..svm import SVC
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..linear_model.base import CoefSelectTransformerMixin
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .least_angle import Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LARS, LassoLARS, \
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_cross_validation.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..datasets import make_regression
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Parallel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_grid_search.py", line 12, in <module>
    from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/grid_search.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_hmm.py", line 6, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_spd_matrix
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Parallel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_multiclass.py", line 13, in <module>
    from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..linear_model.base import CoefSelectTransformerMixin
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .least_angle import Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LARS, LassoLARS, \
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Parallel)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_pipeline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..svm import SVC
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .classes import SVC, NuSVC, SVR, NuSVR, OneClassSVM, LinearSVC
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/svm/classes.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ..linear_model.base import CoefSelectTransformerMixin
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .least_angle import Lars, LassoLars, lars_path, LARS, LassoLARS, \
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/linear_model/least_angle.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..cross_validation import check_cv
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/cross_validation.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
ImportError: cannot import name Parallel

======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: ImportError (cannot import name Memory)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/loader.py", line 390, in loadTestsFromName
    addr.filename, addr.module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 39, in importFromPath
    return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/importer.py", line 86, in importFromDir
    mod = load_module(part_fqname, fh, filename, desc)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_pls.py", line 3, in <module>
    from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .lfw import load_lfw_pairs
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..externals.joblib import Memory
ImportError: cannot import name Memory

======================================================================
FAIL: Test either above import has failed for some reason
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/sklearn/tests/test_init.py", line 22, in test_import_skl
    assert_equal(_top_import_error, None)
AssertionError: ImportError('cannot import name Parallel',) != None

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 100 tests in 6.478s

FAILED (errors=26, failures=1)
```

Comment: Are all the required libraries (step 1.1.1 of your guide) installed with the correct version?

Comment: It seems joblib isn't properly installed. That's strange, since scikit-learn ships it own copy of that library. Could you try `import joblib` and `from sklearn.externals import joblib` in a Python interpreter?

Comment: I tried `import joblib` in the python interpreter and it says `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>  ImportError: No module named joblib`

Comment: @Cynical I installed all the libraries in step1.1.1 except for python-numpy-dev because when I install it the bash prompts `Note,selecting 'python-numpy' instead of 'python-numpy-dev' python-numpy is already the newst version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `python-joblib` package is installed

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep joblib
```

If nothing is returned, try running

```
apt-cache search joblib
```

there should be a package named `python-joblib`: install it using

```
sudo apt-get install python-joblib
```

and retry.

**EDIT**:

You are right, that package is installed, but Python seems unable to find it (proved by your `import joblib` fail). Normally this means that the path where the package has been installed is not part of the Python's search path.

What you can do is either manually install the module from the source and specify the path (which seems to be `/usr/lib/python2.7`), or use a tool such as `easy_install` or `pip` to do that for you.

As stated in your guide, `pip install -U scikit-learn` or `easy_install -U scikit-learn` should do the trick for you, since your libraries are already there...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I run your first command and it returned like this:"ii  python-joblib 0.5.4-1                                             tools to provide lightweight pipelining in Python"

Comment: What about `dpkg -s python-joblib`?

Comment: the output is `Package: python-joblib
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: python
Installed-Size: 184
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Source: joblib
Version: 0.5.4-1
Depends: python, python-support (>= 0.90.0)
Recommends: python-numpy, python-nose, python-simplejson
 .`. It seems that python-joblib is installed properly. and the errors I encounterd also about the parallel and memory

Comment: I run the command `easy_install -U scikit-learn`then I try`nosetests --exe sklearn`,the errors are gone and I prints `Ran 1140 tests in 57.793s OK(SKIP=10)`.It seems that it's ok now. Thanks!!

Comment: Glad that it helped. Please mark the answer as accepted, so that other users will know how you solved.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to manually install joblib, it is included in sklearn.

Comment: I've never tried that tool, so I didn't know that, thanks. Anyway, I thought it would be good to check whether it was installed :)